# Notificaciones tardan en llegar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification, expo

Mi proyecto esta hecho en react native y expo, asi tambien uso el api de expo para enviar notificaciones push a mis usuarios.

Pero tengo el problema de que algunas notifciaciones push llegan bastante tader, a que se puede deber este caso?, ya tengo alta prioridad a las notificaciones push desde mi codigo en react native, a que se puede dever que las notificaiones lleguen tarde?

Comment: Recuerda agregar más información para obtener buenas respuestas, revisa [ask], saludos